# Node gives error about a non-existent code line on vscode platform

Tags: node.js, vscode-extensions, tsc, hardhat

I have a ts file which starts like below. Still I am getting error about the import statement which is commented. I first execute `tsc .\scripts\utility\deploy_utility.ts` and then `node .\scripts\utility\deploy_utility.ts` on the second command I am getting this meaningless error.

I tried to use `npm cache clean` and  `npm cache verify` but they didn't help. This happended before about abother import statement and I restarted vscode and then it was fixed. Now, somehow even restarting Vscode does not work..

I hope someone can help me.. I am new to Vscode and also to node, npm etc..
Kind Regards,
S.

```
`//import '@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers';
const hre = require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
`
```

I tried cleaning cache and also restart IDE